# How does Linux uprobe handle breakpoint?

Tags: c, exception, linux-kernel, trace, kprobe

From what I understand, on x86, `uprobe` places an `int3` instruction at the user specified location, and handles that exception when it is hit, somewhat similar to `kprobe` in that regard.

What I do not understand, it how the `do_int3()` execption handler tells `uprobe` when it is hit. In comparison, for `kprobe`, there is call to `kprobe_int3_handler` inside `do_int3`, so my question is, how and where does `uprobe` register its handlers?

Here is the `do_int3` from kernel 5.7 on x86:

```
dotraplinkage void notrace do_int3(struct pt_regs *regs, long error_code)
{
    if (poke_int3_handler(regs))
        return;

    if (!user_mode(regs)) {
        rcu_nmi_enter();
        preempt_disable();
    }
    RCU_LOCKDEP_WARN(!rcu_is_watching(), "entry code didn't wake RCU");

#ifdef CONFIG_KGDB_LOW_LEVEL_TRAP
    if (kgdb_ll_trap(DIE_INT3, "int3", regs, error_code, X86_TRAP_BP,
                SIGTRAP) == NOTIFY_STOP)
        goto exit;
#endif /* CONFIG_KGDB_LOW_LEVEL_TRAP */

#ifdef CONFIG_KPROBES
    if (kprobe_int3_handler(regs))
        goto exit;
#endif

    if (notify_die(DIE_INT3, "int3", regs, error_code, X86_TRAP_BP,
            SIGTRAP) == NOTIFY_STOP)
        goto exit;

    cond_local_irq_enable(regs);
    do_trap(X86_TRAP_BP, SIGTRAP, "int3", regs, error_code, 0, NULL);
    cond_local_irq_disable(regs);

exit:
    if (!user_mode(regs)) {
        preempt_enable_no_resched();
        rcu_nmi_exit();
    }
}
```